# How to instruct surefire plugin to run just one test, using command line?

Tags: java, maven-2

Is it possible to instruct `maven-surefire-plugin` to run just one unit test? And of course I want to do it from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn -Dtest=testClassName test`

**See also:**

- [Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)